# SQL Query search for itemID = 0 and Groups that have these itemID's and more

Tags: sql

I like to write a query where i filter ItemID's and GroupID's.

I want to know which GroupID's have Items with an ItemID = 0 and have more items.
When a GroupID has an ItemID that is like 0 it can not have any other items.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
  [GroupID]
  ,[ItemID] 
FROM [Store].[dbo].[Items]
where [ItemID] like '0'
```

I am really new to sql and do not know how to get it to the next step.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using with your desired result.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I can't figure out what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `group by` and `having`.

> I want to know which GroupID's have Items with an ItemID = 0 and have more items.

This would be:

```
select GroupId
from Items i
group by GroupId
having sum(case when ItemId = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has "0" and
       sum(case when ItemId <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This can be simplified with some (reasonable) assumptions.  If "0" is the minimum `ItemId` and there are no duplicates then:

```
where min(ItemId) = 0 and count(*) > 1
```

> When a GroupID has an ItemID that is like 0 it can not have any other items.

If you want groups that only have item 0, then:

```
where min(ItemId) = 0 and max(ItemId) = 0
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It gives me the groupnumber that has an itemID of 0 and another random itemID! Tahnk you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
select groupid, Count(*) as countItem
FROM [Store].[dbo].[Items]
where [ItemID] like '0'
group by groupid
having Count(*)>0
```

If you want to see only the groups with more than 1 `[ItemID] like '0'` change `having Count(*)>0` to `having Count(*)>1`

That being said `like '0'` will be the same as `=0`. Perhaps you want to use a wildcard such as `%` ?

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select i.*
from [Store].[dbo].[Items] i
where itemID = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from [Store].[dbo].[Items] i1 
                  where i1.GroupID = t.GroupID and 
                        i1.ItemID <> t.ItemID
                 );
```

Comment: This is almost what i want. it now shows all the groups that have item with an ID of 0 and how many itemID's are 0. But i also want to know if the group has an ItemId different from 0.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate `count` function `having` clause

```
select groupid
FROM [Store].[dbo].[Items]
where [ItemID]=0
group by groupid
having Count(*)>0
```